# Convert Integer input to corresponding cell row VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro to email a row of data based on user input of the row they select. What I need is to convert the input into the corresponding cell row. For instance: User types into the input box "3", then the values in row 3 are emailed. When I manually do the range in the code, the email works fine. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Right now, my code is :

```
myValue = InputBox("Which row are you sending?") 
ActiveSheet.Range(myValue.Rows).Select 
With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope .Introduction = "Blah" 
    .Item.To = ActiveSheet.range("G2").Value 
    .Item.Subject = "Blah" 
    .Item.Send
End with
```

Comment: Your question does not contain any information on how you try to do things. Add (parts of) your code to show the community what it is you are doing and where things go south. Currently your question is only open to guessing ...

Comment: **Help us to help you, post your current code.**

Answer (score 0):

In your With statement, you would need to add to the body of the email the content of the row they selected

```
.Item.Body = Range("A"& myValue).End(xlRight).Value
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How can I trim that range to just columns A-G in that row?

Comment: The End(xlRight) will bring you to the rightmost cell with data in it, to change the range to only contain A-G you would say: Range("A"& myValue & ":G" & myValue)

Comment: Ok I understand. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, if this helped, please upvote and select as answered, as it helps to build the community

Comment: Will do! Now for the .Item.To...The value will always be in column G of that row. Is there something similar to the $G$ functionality in VBA?

Comment: Do you want the value to always come from G2? Or do you want it to come from column G of the row the user selected? If you want it to come from column G use:     .Item.To = ActiveSheet.range("G"& myValue).Value

Comment: Yes always from G. This is what I have now:
`myValue = InputBox("Which row are you sending?")
ActiveSheet.range("A" & myValue).End ("G" & myValue)
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
.Introduction = "Blah"
.Item.To = ActiveSheet.range("G" & myValue).Value
      .Item.Subject = "Blah"
      '.Item.Body = range("A" & myValue).End("G" & myValue).Value
      .Item.Send`

Gives an error "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: When you identify the ranges, they should be held within one set of parenthesis such as: ("A3:G3"), which is what you would get if you had: ("A" & myValue & ":G" & myValue)

Comment: `Item.Body = range("A" & myValue &: "G" & myValue).Value`

Gives an expression error

Comment: Oh! My mistake there. You need to create a variable, and hold the value: rangeVal = "A" & myValue &: "G" & myValue in it, then write the statement as:    Item.Body = range(rangeVal).Value

Comment: I think the "&:" is incorrect syntax. But I understand what you're getting at.

Comment: The & is the String concatenation character for VBA

Comment: Right. I think the issue is with the colon. Code won't compile because "Expected:Expression" error

Comment: My mistake again, the colon should be inside of the quotes

Comment: "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Think i figured that out. Any idea what "400" means? When I run my macro, the display is a msg box saying "400"

Comment: I don't think I've ever run into that

Comment: `Sub Send_Range()
    
    Dim myValue As Integer
   
    myValue = InputBox("Which row are you sending?")        

    Dim rangeVal As range

    Set rangeVal = ActiveSheet.range("A1:G2").Select

    rangeVal = ActiveSheet.range("A" & myValue & ":G" & myValue)

    'ActiveSheet.range(rangeVal).Value
    
   ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
   
   With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Introduction = "Blah"
      .Item.To = ActiveSheet.range("G" & myValue).Value
      .Item.Subject = "Blah"
      .Item.Body = range(rangeVal).Value
      .Item.Send
      
   End With
End Sub`

Comment: It says "Object required" after running. I think something is a little weird with my initialization of the range object.